# How to make a real-time dashboard?

Tags: hadoop, d3.js, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a problem making real-time dashboard, which visualize my log information from HDFS. Below is sketch of my design, my log information is generated from the fly so I use Kafka and Streaming Spark to deal with it. But after exporting from Streaming Spark, I don't know how to visualize it to a local website. Could you give me any idea to do so?

`Data input in HDFS --> Kafka --> Streaming Spark --> ? --> Front-end web (d3js,...)`

Thank you

P/s: Kafka and Streaming Spark are managed by Ambari server, HDP 2.4

Comment: Perhaps put it in Elasticsearch and use Kibana?

Comment: @BinaryNerd: I think of a web server build by node.js and angular.js for back end and front end. In this case, data from Streaming Spark will write down to  MongoDB. Another method is what you said, combination between Apache Flink + Elasticsearch + Kibana, I get the problem with this method, I do not know how to make Apache Flink work with my cluster. Which method do you think is easy to implement and efficient for my case?